# Get array based on another array

Tags: powershell, csv

I need to take a CSV file and then create many files out of that in different formats depending on the account number.  The account numbers I need are in other files with no other fields (I need to pad them to match). This is just one below.

I know I can cycle through using foreach, but was trying to avoid that. This gives no error, but doesn't work even though I know there are matches.

```
$sms_accts = import-csv -path "H:\scrap\Positive Pay Feeds\sms_accounts.txt"
$input_file = import-csv -path "H:\scrap\Positive Pay Feeds\CNVDC939.POSITIVE PAY ISSUES.txt"

$sms_accts = $sms_accts  | Select-Object @{Name="Acct";Expression={$_.Acct.PadLeft(11,"0")}}

$to_sms_file = $input_file  | where-object { $sms_accts -contains ($_.ACCOUNT_NUMBER.PadLeft(11,"0"))  }

$to_sms_file
```

It returns nothing.

Sample file below.

sms_accounts.txt:

```
Acct
12345678
23456789


Positive Pay:
    "SPONSOR_BANK_ID","BE_CLIENT_ID","COMPANY_NAME","ACCOUNT_NUMBER","SERIAL","AMOUNT","PAYEE","ISSUE_TYPE","STATUS","ENTRY_DATE","ISSUE_DATE"
    "100741","1004928","Acme","0012345678","11111","2468","","0","1","2/11/2014 5:50:34 PM","2/10/2014"
    "100741","1004928","ABC","009999999","22222","180.34","","0","1","2/20/2014 9:01:38 PM","2/20/2014"
```

Comment: Can you give example for the CSV files (headers with fake but coherent  contents)?

Comment: See above for sample files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You process `$sms_accts` into an array of *custom objects* with the single property `Acct`:

```
$sms_accts = $sms_accts  | Select-Object @{Name="Acct";Expression={$_.Acct.PadLeft(11,"0")}}
```

but then check the array for a particular *string*:

```
... | where-object { $sms_accts -contains ($_.ACCOUNT_NUMBER.PadLeft(11,"0")) }
```

Since none of your custom objects is a string (even though each has a string property), you don't get a match. Change the two lines

```
$sms_accts = import-csv -path "H:\scrap\Positive Pay Feeds\sms_accounts.txt"
```

and

```
$sms_accts = $sms_accts  | Select-Object @{Name="Acct";Expression={$_.Acct.PadLeft(11,"0")}}
```

into this:

```
$sms_accts = Import-Csv "H:\scrap\Positive Pay Feeds\sms_accounts.txt" | % {
               $_.Acct.PadLeft(11,"0")
             }
```

and your check will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks. That works. I think I get what you are saying. What if the file had more fields than account number though?  How could I use it?

Comment: @user1921849 That depends on what you actually want to do with it.

Comment: I am saying I want to do the exact thing- look for matches- but if the file had acct+other columns.  Like is there a way to use my original custom object in the Where-Object.

Comment: @user1921849 Matches of *what*? For matches of any single field (`Acct` or whatever) you'd do the same thing: turn it into an array and check if the array `-contains` a given value. If you want to check multiple properties you'd need to create just as many arrays. If you have PowerShell v3 or newer you could also use @amirhosseinab's suggestion and do something like this: `$sms_accts.Acct -contains X -and $sms_accts.PropA -contains Y`.

Comment: I did upgrade to PS 4.0 and then $sms_accts.Acct works also with my original code with the .Acct added to the where-object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Acct` property to filter `$sms_accts`

```
... | where-object { $sms_accts.Acct -contains ($_.ACCOUNT_NUMBER.PadLeft(11,"0"))}
```

in this way you don't need to use `foreach` in your code.